# How to abort an installation, when replacing files would require a restart?

Tags: inno-setup

I have an application that runs a scheduled windows task to check for and install updates.

During testing, I managed to break my setup the following way:

- As user, create a file lock on one of the applications' files by calling `notepad <Qt5Core.dll` in cmd
- Have windows task run the installer as "SYSTEM" user

From the logs I can tell, that inno setup correctly identifies that there is a locked file they cannot close, that prevents running an update to the software:

```
2023-09-12 11:14:01.249   Found 36 files to register with RestartManager.
2023-09-12 11:14:01.249   Calling RestartManager's RmGetList.
2023-09-12 11:14:01.296   RmGetList finished successfully.
2023-09-12 11:14:01.296   RestartManager found an application using one of our files: Editor
2023-09-12 11:14:01.296   Can use RestartManager to avoid reboot? No (2: Session Mismatch)
```

If I leave it as is, setup will continue the installation and starts replacing files - until it reaches the locked file. At this point, I observe the following logs:

```
2023-09-12 11:14:05.077   Installing the file.
2023-09-12 11:14:05.093   DeleteFile: The existing file appears to be in use (32). Retrying.
2023-09-12 11:14:06.108   DeleteFile: The existing file appears to be in use (32). Retrying.
2023-09-12 11:14:07.124   DeleteFile: The existing file appears to be in use (32). Retrying.
2023-09-12 11:14:08.140   DeleteFile: The existing file appears to be in use (32). Retrying.
2023-09-12 11:14:09.172   Defaulting to Abort for suppressed message box (Abort/Retry/Ignore):
                          C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\Qt5Core.dll
                          
                          Fehler beim Ersetzen einer vorhandenen Datei:
                          DeleteFile schlug fehl; Code 32.
                          Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird.
2023-09-12 11:14:09.172   User canceled the installation process.
2023-09-12 11:14:09.172   Rolling back changes.
2023-09-12 11:14:09.172   Starting the uninstallation process.
2023-09-12 11:14:09.172   Deleting directory: C:\ProgramData\MyApp
2023-09-12 11:14:09.172   Uninstallation process succeeded.
```

As expected, Inno setup tells me that it cannot replace the locked file. It displays a retry/cancel error that will auto select cancel in the silent installation, again, as expected. Now, the setup says it is `Rolling back changes`. This, however does not happen. At the end of the setup, the locked file remains unchanged while the already replaced files are not reset to the previous version.

This obviously breaks the software and I'd like it to not happen.
How can I either make sure Inno setup stops the installation before replacing things after it noticed the required reboot, or make sure the rollback actually works?

I base my expectations on the following docs:

---

> Restart Manager: If Setup is not running silently and is unable to close all applications using files that need to be updated, it will now ask the user to abort, retry, or ignore.

<sup>[Inno setup 5.5.3 revision history](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is5.5-whatsnew.htm)</sup>

> `/SUPPRESSMSGBOXES`
>
> Instructs Setup to suppress message boxes. Only has an effect when combined with `/SILENT` or `/VERYSILENT`.
>
> The default response in situations where there's a choice is:
>
> ...
>
> Abort in Abort/Retry situations.

<sup>[Commandline parameters documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=SUPPRESSMSGBOXES)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of other solution than forcing installer logging in your scheduled task and parsing the log in the installer itself, looking for

> Can use RestartManager to avoid reboot? No

If you find it, abort the installation in `CurStepChanged(ssInstall)`.

---

If you would not have to deal with installer running from Task Scheduler (i.e. in an environment with no user session), you can abort the installation when a silent installer ever "clicks" the *Next* button on the `wpPreparing` page:

```pascal
procedure ExitProcess(uExitCode: Integer);
  external 'ExitProcess@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if (CurPageID = wpPreparing) and WizardSilent then
  begin
    Log('Silent installer would need to restart applications or computer, aborting...');
    ExitProcess(1);
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

It's not perfect as it aborts even when the application could be restarted. You can improve that by introducing new command-line parameter for this scenario.